Fantasy book about a druid
I don't remember too many specific details about the book. M'm pretty sure the title was Taliesin.
I think the main character was a woman who was also a musician who played Celtic music. I think there was a ring that was somehow involved in bringing a druid from the past into the present.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you remember the cover art?  What instrument did the musician play?

Possibly Moonheart by Charles deLint ? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonheart

That's it! As soon as I saw the cover I knew it was right. Thanks so much!

Could this be Taliesin by Stephen R. Lawhead?

It was a time of legend, when the last shadows of the mighty Roman
conqueror faded from the captured Isle of Britain. While across a vast
sea, bloody war shattered a peace that had flourished for two thousand
years in the doomed kingdom of Atlantis.
Taliesin is the remarkable adventure of Charis, the Atlantean princess
who escaped the terrible devastation of her homeland, and of the
fabled seer and druid prince Taliesin, singer at the dawn of the age.
It is the story of an incomparable love that joined two worlds amid
the fires of chaos, and spawned the miracles of Merlin...and Arthur
the king.


Lots and lots of references to druids, magical enchanted rings, prophecy, etc etc

But time travel?  Women musicians?  I admit, it's the first thing I thought of too, but wasn't Taliesin a way more important character than Charis?

@DavidW - It's not the only choice. There's this as well; https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35909123-taliesin---choice-destiny?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=bUpAbQ8M8j&rank=5

In a comment above, OP confirmed that this was Moonheart by Charles de Lint. From the author's website:

When Sara and Jamie discovered the seemingly ordinary artifacts, they
sensed the pull of a dim and distant place. A world of mists and
forests, of ancient magics, mythical beings, ageless bards..and
restless evil. Now, with their friends and enemies alike—Blue, the
biker; Keiran, the folk musician; the Inspector from the RCMP; and the
mysterious Tom Hengyr—Sara and Jamie are drawn into this enchanted
land through the portals of Tamson House, that sprawling downtown
edifice that straddles two worlds.

